# Patching a custom patch config file to change the order

Tags: helix, patch-configuration

I am trying to patch a file (already a patch) so that it can be loaded after that, but the patching is not working.

Below is the scenario:

1. Create a patch config file for loading the DI configurator in the foundation layer
2. Now trying to patch the DI configurator for a feature so that it loads after the foundation's patch file using the **patch:after** syntax.
3. When I check the order in the showconfig.aspx then feature's patch is not loading after the foundation's config but it is loading before the foundation config as shown in the screenshot below.

[image]

FYI: below is the syntax that I have used for patching:

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:set="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/set/">
    <sitecore>
      <services>
         <configurator type="DDD.Feature.Documents.Pipelines.RegisterGenericTypes, DDD.Feature.Documents" patch:after="*[@type='BBB.Foundation.DependencyInjection.Infrastructure.MvcControllerServicesConfigurator,BBB.Foundation.DependencyInjection']"/>
      </services>
    </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

But if I do **patch:before** or **patch:after** for any sitecore type then it works. For example, in the screenshot you can see the top line like `Sitecore.Services.Infrastructure.Sitecore.DependencyInjection.....`, if I will do **path:after** or **patch:before** for it then patching works.

I am not sure if patching an already patched file is allowable or not. If so then please let me know where am I making the gap in the config?

Even I checked the loadOrder it seems to be fine as following:

```
<layer name="Custom" includeFolder="/App_Config/Include/">
    <loadOrder>
      <add path="Rainbow.config" type="File" />
      <add path="Unicorn" type="Folder" />
      <add path="Foundation" type="Folder" />
      <add path="Feature" type="Folder" />
      <add path="Project" type="Folder" />
    </loadOrder>
  </layer>
```

Comment: Are your files properly added in the correct folder?

Comment: Try moving the config to a `zzz.Last` folder and check if the patching order is correct. It will let you know if it's an issue with the config or load order.

Comment: Yes file is in Foundation folder @Hishaam

Comment: @jammykam, I noticed one thing that if move file from Foundation folder to Feature folder then it patchhing works in correct load order. Any idea why is this not working with Foundation folder.

Comment: @jammykam, even it is not working in zzz.Last folder created in the Foundation folder, but when I move the file from the Foundation to a folder name starting from letter A in the feature folder, then patching works fine.

Comment: Prashant, Can you please let me know which Sitecore version - are you using? Because i believe loadOrder concept came after Sitecore 9.

Comment: @Pradeep, we were using 9.3 but due to client requirement we had degraded it to 8.2 so I think this Layer.config remained in the app_config folder as part of degrade, which was misguiding me. Now the problem is solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the loadOrder concept was introduced in Sitecore 9.x that is why LoadOrder not working as expected for your 8.2.

So please try considering configs to be loaded in alphabetical order.